# How to wait for first Observable to finish before executing others in parallel using RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

At the moment I have all 3 requests running in parallel. Now I need to wait for the first one to finish before I fire the other 2 in parallel. This is what I have at the moment:

```
return Observable
   .forkJoin(request1, request2, request3)
   .map((successValues: boolean[]) => {
      return successValues.every(x => x);
   })
   .do(success => {
      if (success) {
         this.store.dispatch({
            type: actions.UPDATE_SUCCESS
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `switchMap` operator.

```
request1.switchMap(response1 => {
    Observable
   .forkJoin(request2, request3)
   .map((successValues: boolean[]) => {
      return successValues.every(x => x);
   })
   .do(success => {
      if (success) {
         this.store.dispatch({
            type: actions.UPDATE_SUCCESS
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, there are some missing braces in your example, but apart from that it worked like a charm! Thanks