# Angular2: GET request not running synchronously

Tags: angular, http

I have problem with HTTP GET request.. The code is not running synchronously.. Below is my example code:

```
this.jilidService.getDBList().subscribe(
      data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.data = data;

          this.db_name[i] = this.data[i]
          this.dbname = this.db_name[i]
          console.log("1")

        }
      },
    );
    this.jilidService.getFileList(this.dbname).subscribe(
      data1 => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
          this.data = data1;

          this.filename = data1[i]
          console.log("2")
        }
      },
    );
```

When I run the code the result that I got from console log is:

```
2
1
```

The result that I want is:

```
1
2
```

Comment: you might consider using `switchmap` or `flatmap` in this case as these are async calls

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct. HTTP calls are asynchronous is nature. This is how they work. You issue an HTTP **REQUEST** and at some future point in time you receive an HTTP **RESPONSE**. HTTP has always been this way.

[image]

The method passed into the subscribe is a basically a callback function that is called back when the response is received.

One way to resolve your issue is to put the second call within the callback function of the first. Like this:

```
this.jilidService.getDBList().subscribe(
      data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          this.data = data;

          this.db_name[i] = this.data[i]
          this.dbname = this.db_name[i]
          console.log("1")

        }

       this.jilidService.getFileList(this.dbname).subscribe(
         data1 => {
           for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
             this.data = data1;

             this.filename = data1[i]
             console.log("2")
           }
         },
       );
      },
    );
```

Another option is to use switchMap as suggested by Rahul. You can find an example of that here:

[How to wait for first Observable to finish before executing others in parallel using RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40164578/how-to-wait-for-first-observable-to-finish-before-executing-others-in-parallel-u)